# Show that integral is finite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

For $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $y>\frac{n}{2}$ define
$$
I_n\colon (n/2,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^y}\, d\lambda(x),
$$
where $\lVert x\rVert=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert x_i\rvert^2}$.

I would like to show that $I_n<\infty$.

---

To this end, the idea was to split $\mathbb{R}^n$ into
$$
A_1:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert x\rVert\leqslant 1\}\quad\textrm{and}\quad A_2:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert x\rVert\geqslant 1\}, 
$$
resulting in
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^y}\, d\lambda =\underbrace{\int_{A_1}\frac{1}{(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^y}\, d\lambda}_{=: I_1} + \underbrace{\int_{A_2}\frac{1}{(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^y}\, d\lambda}_{=:I_2}.
$$

- As to $I_1$, I think one can simply use $1+\lVert x\rVert^2\geq 1$ and estimate by
  $$
  I_1\leqslant\int_{A_1}\, d\lambda=\textrm{vol}(B_1(0))<\infty,
  $$
  where $B_1(0)$ is the n-dim. unit ball.
- As to the integral $I_2$, the idea is very similar: Since $1+\lVert x\rVert^2\geqslant\lVert x\rVert^2$, and $2y>n$,
  $$
  I_2\leqslant \int_{A_2}\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^{2y}}\, d\lambda < \infty.
  $$
  (The function $x\longmapsto\lVert x\rVert^{-\alpha}$ is integrable over $A_2$ exactly if $\alpha>n$.)

Would be great to get some verification from you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this proof is correct.

Note you have a small typo in your definition of $I_n$ at the top: you wrote $x \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^y}\, d\lambda(x),$ but you meant $y \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^y}\, d\lambda(x),$.